# Reversing words in a string in c as i tried implemented in a naive way

Tags: c, string, reverse

So my code was supposed to reverse the words in a string over testcases specified but it picks up second everything until last string and with each testcase input string repeats and concatenates with the previous string read.

> INPUT  3: i am fine foobar good is ok
>
> results showing : am i foobar

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define MAXCHARS 1000
#define MAXWORDS 1000

typedef char word_t[MAXCHARS+1];
int getwords(char W[]);

int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    word_t oneword, all_words[MAXWORDS];
    int num_words = 0,value;
    int testcases,i,n;

    scanf("%d",&testcases);

    getchar();

    for(i =1;i<=testcases;i++){  
        while((value = getwords(oneword))!=1){  
            strcpy(all_words[num_words],oneword);
            num_words++;
  
            /*if(value ==1){
            value = 2;
             }*/
        }
  
        printf("Case #%d:",i);
  
        for(n=num_words;n>=0;n--){
            printf("%s",all_words[n]);
        }
  
        printf("\n"); 
    }

    return 0;
}

int getwords(char W[]){
    int c,len =0,NewSpaceOrline =0;

    while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
        W[len] = c;
        len++;
    
        if(c == ' '){
            W[len] = '\0';
            NewSpaceOrline =0;
            return NewSpaceOrline;  
        }

    }

    W[len] ='\0';
    NewSpaceOrline =1; 

    return NewSpaceOrline;  

}
```

Comment: Please rephrase question

Comment: add `strcpy(all_words[num_words], oneword); strcat(all_words[num_words], " ");` after while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you don't reset `num_words` between test cases.

Try:

```
for(i =1;i<=testcases;i++){  
    num_words = 0;    // New test case so start from zero
```

Also this part has a problem:

```
    for(n=num_words;n>=0;n--){
        printf("%s",all_words[n]);
    }
```

as you start from `all_words[num_words]` which you have never filled.

Try:

```
    for(n=num_words-1;n>=0;n--){      // Notice the -1
        printf("%s ",all_words[n]);   // Notice the space
    }
```

Another problem is that you never copy the last word:

```
    while((value = getwords(oneword))!=1){  
        strcpy(all_words[num_words],oneword);
        // ....
    }
```

so when your function return 1, you never execute the `strcpy`

Maybe you want something like:

```
    while((value = getwords(oneword))!=1){  
        strcpy(all_words[num_words],oneword);
        // ....
    }
    strcpy(all_words[num_words],oneword); // Copy last word
    num_words++;
```

Comment: no luck it does the same thing as before. It just doesnt pick nth term of n words.

Answer (score -1):

I'll give you this function to get started. The rest, I leave for the OP to finish.

```
void rev(char *str)
{
    char *bgn, *end;

    end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    for (bgn = str; end > bgn; --end, ++bgn) {
        char tmp;

        tmp = *bgn;
        *bgn = *end;
        *end = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? At least give an explanation before you downvote

Comment: hey everyone, the issue is with the condition of while and the flags i used to terminate the loop